# Scaling figure to column width in ACM class

Tags: floats, acm, acmart

I'm currently writing a paper using the ACM 2 column class file (`\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}`). I'm including one column figures (jpeg, png) in the following way:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=1in, width=1in]{figures/example}
\caption{This is the caption}
\end{figure}
```

Unforunately, my figure is very small. How can I scale it to column width but keeping the aspect ratio (so that it does not get distorted) while at the same time following the ACM rules?

Comment: You are explicitly telling it to have height and width of `1 in`. You can use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/example}`. This will preserve the aspect ratio unless you also add a `height` option, then you have to use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=some_amount,keepaspectratio]{figures/example}`.

Comment: Use `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{<filename>}`

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: after Zarko's comment:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figures/example}
\caption{This is the caption}
\end{figure}
```

You can omit writing height

Comment: Why not simple `includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{figures/example}`?

Comment: this works thanks Zarko I will edit the answer after your comment.